# Correctly configuring split dns with systemd-resolved?

Tags: systemd, dns, networkmanager, systemd-resolved

I would like requests for hosts in the `example.com` domain to go to a local DNS resolver hosted at 172.31.64.1, and all other requests to be handled by the default resolvers.

The resolver at 172.31.64.1 is up and configured correctly:

```
$ dig files.example.com @172.31.64.1
files.example.com.      590     IN      A       172.21.0.4
$ dig www.example.com @172.31.64.1
www.example.com.        600     IN      A       172.21.0.2
```

The address 172.31.64.1 belongs to a local bridge interface:

```
$ ip addr show br-infra
1021: br-infra: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:52:36:61:79:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.64.1/24 brd 172.31.64.255 scope global noprefixroute br-infra
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The resolved configuration for the primary and br-infra interfaces looks like this:

```
$ resolvectl status eth0
Link 2 (eth0)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
        DNS Domain: house
$ resolvectl status br-infra
Link 1065 (br-infra)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 172.31.64.1
    DNS Domain: example.com
```

Despite this configuration, requests for hsots in the `example.com` domain are being routed to the default DNS servers.  E.g, running `tcpdump -i any -n port domain` in one terminal and `dig files.example.com` in another terminal, I see:

```
13:52:02.879796 lo    In  IP 127.0.0.1.45497 > 127.0.0.53.domain: 16287+ [1au] A? files.example.com. (58)
13:52:02.880003 eth0  Out IP 192.168.1.200.58863 > 192.168.1.1.domain: 7738+ A? files.example.com. (35)
13:52:02.899060 eth0  In  IP 192.168.1.1.domain > 192.168.1.200.58863: 7738 NXDomain 0/1/0 (91)
13:52:02.899123 lo    In  IP 127.0.0.53.domain > 127.0.0.1.45497: 16287 NXDomain 0/1/1 (102)
```

The request is being routed to the default DNS server at 192.168.1.1.

What's missing from this configuration?

Comment: Good setup. What I'm missing is the contents of your /etc/resolv.conf and how it is managed (I have a soft link to /usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf or /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf)

Comment: And I have my default DNS set up in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf with 'DNS=' and Domains='. The specifics go to link setup in /etc/systemd/network/<mac>.network. How do you do it?

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` (and isn't "managed" as such; it's static and always points at systemd-resolvd). I'm managing network configuration with NetworkManager.

Comment: Then I would check the dns settings in 'man nm-settings' for the files in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*.nmconnections'. Especially 'domain-suffix-match' looks promissing. I use, as you may have figured out by now, a combination of systemd-resolved and systemd-networkd. I _do_ augment my dns settings with /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/dispatch_script locally on the laptop.

Comment: Are you suggesting that you see problems in the output of `resolvectl status`? Because there we see that the `br-infra` link has both `DNS Servers` and `DNS Domain` set appropriately with the current configuration.

Comment: Yeah, but the trick in resolvectl is that there is a 'global' setting, for the fall back nameservers. You get it with 'resolvectl' without a nic.

Comment: Those you set in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.

Comment: Right, but I don't care about the global/fallback configuration (that works fine). The issue here is that requests for "example.com" aren't getting routed to the right nameserver.

Comment: Need my working config?

Comment: `Current Scopes: none` on your `br-infra` link, i think it's self explanatory. it has no scope so it is not being used.